# Hubspot API Not Populating Deal

Tags: python, api, python-requests, crm, hubspot

When I'm trying to create a deal through the hubspot api, all that is being created is a completely blank deal even though I am passing through populated data

Api Url: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/deals

Here is the following code that I am trying:

```
import json

import requests

hubspot_api_key = "MY_API_KEY"

url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals?hapikey={}'.format(hubspot_api_key)

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
deals_post = {
    'amount': "4034.75",
    'closedate': '2021-05-10T12:04:00.000Z',
    'dealname': 'Custom data integrations',
    'dealstage': 'closedwon',
    'hubspot_owner_id': "5448459615",
    'pipeline': 'default'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(deals_post))
print(response.text)
```

And here is the result of it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue would be adding properties to the data dictionary

```
import json

import requests

hubspot_api_key = "MY_API_KEY"

url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals?hapikey={}'.format(hubspot_api_key)

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
deals_post = {
    'properties': {
        'amount': "4034.75",
        'closedate': '2021-05-10T12:04:00.000Z',
        'dealname': 'Custom data integrations',
        'dealstage': 'closedwon',
        'hubspot_owner_id': 83849850,
        'pipeline': 'default'
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(deals_post))
print(response.text)
```

This results in a filled out deal according to the data that was passed in